# Notation for the "scalarization" of a vector with a single non-zero entry

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

Suppose I have a vector $v$ in the complex space $\mathbb{C}^N$ with only a single non-zero element.  Is there a standard notation to replace the vector with a scalar equal to the non-zero value of the vector?

Update:

After some thought, I think $v\cdot e_i$ would suffice for this purpose, assuming the index i containing the non-zero element is known.  But what if the index is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot product with the vector $(1, \dots, 1)^T$.

Comment: That's so simple and it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. Why not use
$$
s \, e_k =<v,e_k>\,e_k
$$
with a canonical vector $(e_k)_i = \delta_{ki}$.